# Find the $2013$th power of a given $3\times 3$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Question from my linear algebra homework I'm struggling with:

Let $D = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 5 & 4 \\-1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 4 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$

We are asked:

1. Find $D^5+3D^2-D+I$
2. Find $D^{2013}$
3. Write $D^{-1}$ as a polynomial of $D$

I solved questions 1) and 3) but can't solve 2)...

Comment: Did you find a diagonalization?

Comment: it is not diagonlizable

Comment: Oops, by bad...

Comment: You could use Sage to compute the first 10 powers. Then it shouldn't be difficult to spot a pattern. Or you can use Sage to just compute the answer immediately.

Comment: beats the entire point of the question. I could also use matlab and find $D^{2013}$ but the point is to do it by hand, there has to be a trick here.

Comment: @Oria can you use complex numbers?

Comment: @Gregor: I guess they don't want you to use a CA system for doing your homework. In fact I guess whoever posed this question already know the answer, but wants the students to think about finding an answer.

Comment: @OriaGruber: Well, then compute the first ten powers by hand.

Comment: I posted this question. I don't know the answer (As in, I can compute it with matlab) but i don't know how to solve it by hand. complex numbers are fine

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Or, that person meant to post a diagonalizable matrix ;).

Comment: I guess posting what $D^{-1}$ and $D^5+3D^2-D+I$ would be of some help to go further... (Not so sure if this is really helpful)

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Or they maybe want them to get used to CA systems.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form

Comment: it might be better to do this first for corresponding jordan form...  this may give some idea...

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354277/square-matrix-multiplication-when-raised-to-a-power), [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326688/why-does-the-n-th-power-of-a-jordan-matrix-involve-the-binomial-coefficient), [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431095/the-index-of-nilpotency-of-a-nilpotent-matrix) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409601/if-modulus-of-each-one-of-eigenvalues-of-b-is-less-than-1-then-bk-rightar) for examples of the technique to apply to your problem.

Comment: I think the point is to use polynomial division and cayley-hamilton theorem, we didnt study jordan form yet so i dont think thats the way

Comment: Similarly to diagonalizing D, which is not possible, you can find the Jordan form such that $D=PJP^{-1}$ TonyK's answer gives you J. In short, the Jordan matrix has a 1 between similar eigenvalues. You should know how to do the rest

Comment: So, have you computed D’s characteristic polynomial $p$? What do you know about $D^{2013}$ and the polynomial $x^{2013} \mod p$?

Comment: You need neither Jordan normal forms nor computer algebra to solve this.

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is how I would attack such a question. You need to find a polynomial equation satisfied by$~D$ first. You could use the characteristic polynomial for that (by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem), but knowing that such a polynomial of degree at most$~3$ exists, you can also just try to find a relation between some powers of$~D$. The sparse second line suggests right-multiplying powers of $D$ to $(0~1~0)$, giving the sequence $(0~1~0),(-1~0~0),(2~{-}5~{-}4),(3~{-}6~{-}4)$. The first three are clearly linearly independent, and the fourth one gives the relation $(0~1~0)-(-1~0~0)-(2~{-}5~{-}4)+(3~{-}6~{-}4)=(0~0~0)$, so your polynomial equation should be $I-D^1-D^2+D^3=0$, which you can check to be true. Now $X^3-X^2-X+1=(X-1)(X^2-1)=(X-1)^2(X+1)$. Indeed your matrix is not diagonalisable because of the double root.

To compute $X^{2013}$ you can take its remainder$~R$ after division by $P=(X-1)(X^2+1)$, so that $X^{2013}=PQ+R$ for some (quotient)$~Q$. For finding the remainder after division by a polynomial with such easy (complex) roots as $P$ has, the standard trick to avoid doing a (very) long division of polynomials is write the remainder as a polynomial of degree${}<\deg P=3$ with unknown coefficients: $R=aX^2+bX+c$, and evaluate the equation $X^{2013}=PQ+R$ at the roots of$~P$; since these substitutions annihilate the term $PQ$ regardless of$~Q$, they give you linear equations in $a,b,c$. The problem here is that you have only two roots $1,-1$ to substitute, although $1$ is a double root of the minimal polynomial. There is another trick to solve this shortage of equations: since $1$ is also a root of the derivative $P'$ of$~P$, you can take the derivative of the equation (being an identity of polynomials in$~X$, this gives an equation that must still hold) giving $2013X^{2012}=P'Q+PQ'+R'$. Now substitute $X=1$ into that to get a third equation that will let you solve $a,b,c$. The answer is $aD^2+bD+cI$.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is indeed the way the question should be solved. I didn't think of deriving. Thanks. top answer.

Answer (score 5):

Although $D$ is not diagonalizable, it has the Jordan decomposition (courtesy of [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Jordan%20decomposition%7B%7B-2,5,4%7D,%7B-1,0,0%7D,%7B0,4,3%7D%7D)):
$$D = SJS^{-1}$$
where

$$S = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 & \frac12 \\-1 & -1 & \frac12 \\1 & 2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$J = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 1 & 1 \\0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

There is a simple closed-form expression for $J^n$, which you should be able to find and prove yourself.

Comment: I think the point is to use polynomial division and cayley-hamilton theorem, we didnt study jordan form yet so i dont think thats the way

Comment: Be careful about what you study, there aren't always epiphany answers.  Jordan normal form is an amazing tool.

Answer (score 5):

The characteristic polynomial of $D$ is given by

$$\chi_D(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I_3 - D) = \lambda^3 - \lambda^2 - \lambda + 1 = (\lambda - 1)^2 (\lambda+1)$$

By Cayley Hamilton theorem, we have

$$\chi_D(D) = D^3 - D^2 - D + I_3 = (D - I_3)^2(D + I_3) = (D^2 - I_3)(D - I_3) = 0$$

Since $(\lambda + 1)\chi_D(\lambda) = (\lambda^2 - 1)^2$, we have
$(D^2 - I_3)^2 = 0$ and hence
$$\begin{align}
D^{2013} 
= & (I_3 + (D^2 - I_3))^{1006} D\\
= & (I_3 + 1006 (D^2 - I_3)) D\quad\color{blue}{\longleftarrow \text{throwing away terms}\propto (D^2 - I_3)^2}\\
= & D + 1006 (D^2 - I_3)((D - I_3) + I_3)\\
= & D + 1006 (D^2 - I_3)\quad\color{blue}{\longleftarrow \text{throwing away terms}\propto (D^2 - I_3)(D-I_3)}\\
= & \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
-2014  & 6041 & 4028 \\
2011 & -6036  &  -4024 \\
-4024  & 12076  & 8051
\end{array}\right]
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Looks all right, but you might bring attention to the fact that in the before-last equality you applied the identity $D^3-D=D^2-I$ that follows from the original polynomial equation. Without that, it looks like you did the algebra wrong.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen thanks for point out that. I've fixed that together with other minus sign errors in the original derivation.

Answer (score 2):

Bull headed approach. 2013 written in binary form is 11111011101.

Therefore, repeatedly square D 10 times which gives you $D$, $D^2$, $D^4$, $D^8$, $D^{16}$, $D^{32}$, $D^{64}$, $D^{128}$, $D^{256}$, $D^{512}$ and $D^{1024}$.

Then multiply $D^{1024} \times D^{512} \times D^{256} \times D^{128} \times D^{64} \times D^{16} \times D^{8} \times D^4$.

So, you will have to perform 17 multiplications, which is doable.

Comment: If you've ever computed $n^{1024}$ for an integer $n\neq\{1,0,-1\}$, there is no reason to be optimistic about computing $D^{1024}$. It happens that this is a very special matrix, and the coefficients of its powers grow only linearly with the exponent. But I don't think there is reason to conclude "doable" without having done it.

Comment: Sure, give me sometime and I will actually do it and write it up. Do you want me to? My point that it was doable precisely because it is a special matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the way to answer this, but I've still run into some trouble.

Basically the Idea is this:

you take the polynomial $t^{2013}$ and you divide it by the characteristic polynomial which is $-t^3+t^2+t-1$ and you get:

$t^{2013} = (-t^3+t^2+t-1)*q(t)+r(t)$ where $deg(r(t)) \leq deg(-t^3+t^2+t-1)-1 = 2$

$t=1$ and $t=-1$ are roots of $-t^3+t^2+t-1$ so if $r(x)=ax^2+bx+c$:

$1^{2013} = a+b+c$ and $(-1)^{2013} = a-b+c$

If we find a b c then we solved the question. But how do we find a b c?